# Writing a list of arrays using csvhelper C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, csvhelper

I am trying to write a `List<double[]>` into a csv file. Based on my experiments it is not possible using `WriteRecords()` directly, so I am looking for alternatives.

I cannot create a class to map this data because the number of elements in the arrays varies from execution to execution, and ranges from 1 to 75.

I have tried to go through each element of the array manually with `WriteField()` but it is really slow., and I have thousands of elements.

Is there anyway to accomplish this fast enough?

Thanks.
Edit:

Code

```
 class ExportData


{
    private Dictionary<int, Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex>> _dict_sensorN;
    private List<double[]> _values_list;
    private int _current_max_Count=-1;
    private static int _max_Count = 3000;
    int n_columns = 0;
    private CsvWriter csv;
    public ExportData(List<SensorControl> sensorsUC)
    {
    //We create a dictionary with two keys that will store all the info from the sensors
      _dict_sensorN = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex>>();

  foreach (SensorControl SensorC in sensorsUC)
  {
    Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex> dict_sensorM = new Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex>();
    if (SensorC.emg)
    {
      ListIndex Index = new ListIndex();
      Index.Column = n_columns;
      Index.Row = 0;
      dict_sensorM.Add(SensorT.EMG, Index);
      n_columns++;
    }
    if (SensorC.triggers)
    {
      ListIndex Index = new ListIndex();
      Index.Column = n_columns;
      Index.Row = 0; 
      dict_sensorM.Add(SensorT.Trigger1, Index);
      n_columns++;
      Index.Column = n_columns;
      Index.Row = 0;
      dict_sensorM.Add(SensorT.Trigger2, Index);
      n_columns++;
    }
    if (SensorC.acc)
    {
      ListIndex Index = new ListIndex();
      Index.Column = n_columns;
      Index.Row = 0;
      dict_sensorM.Add(SensorT.ACC, Index);
      n_columns++;
    }
    _dict_sensorN.Add(SensorC.sensorNumber, dict_sensorM);
  }
  //Initialize the array
  _values_list = new List<double[]>();
  //Initialize the document
  DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
  string fileName = "exp_" + currentDate.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ".csv";
  try
  {
    var textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName);
    csv = new CsvWriter(textWriter);
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\n Cannot create file.");
    return;
  }

}

public void AddToBuffer(SensorPoint sp)
{
  Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex> dict_sensorM = new Dictionary<SensorT, ListIndex>();
  ListIndex Index = new ListIndex();
  if (_dict_sensorN.TryGetValue(sp.ID, out dict_sensorM))
  {
    SensorT type = ToSensorT(sp.SensorType, sp.Battery); 
    if(type == SensorT.Trigger1) {
      if (dict_sensorM.TryGetValue(type, out Index))
      {
        if (_current_max_Count < Index.Row)
        {
          _current_max_Count = Index.Row + 1;
          _values_list[Index.Row] = new double[n_columns];
        }
        _values_list[Index.Row][Index.Column] =sp.Trigger1_int;
        Index.Row++;
        }
      if (dict_sensorM.TryGetValue(SensorT.Trigger2, out Index))
      {
        if (_current_max_Count < Index.Row)
        {
          _current_max_Count = Index.Row + 1;
          _values_list[Index.Row] = new double[n_columns];
        }
        _values_list[Index.Row][Index.Column] = sp.Trigger2_int_pos;
        Index.Row++;
        }
    }
    else {
      if (dict_sensorM.TryGetValue(type, out Index))
      {
        if (_current_max_Count < Index.Row)
        {
          _current_max_Count = Index.Row;
          _values_list.Add(new double[n_columns]);
        }
        _values_list[Index.Row][Index.Column] = sp.YPoint;
        Index.Row++;

      }
    }
  }
  if (_current_max_Count > _max_Count) AddToFile();
}
private void AddToFile() {
csv.WriteRecords(_values_list);
}

private SensorT ToSensorT(SensorType stype, int battery)
{
  if (stype == SensorType.EMG)
  {
    return SensorT.EMG;
  }
  else if (stype == SensorType.EMG_Trigger )
  {
    if (battery < 0) return SensorT.Trigger1;
    else return SensorT.EMG;
  }
  else if (stype == SensorType.ACC)
  {
    return SensorT.ACC;
  }
  else {
    return SensorT.Unknown;
      }
    }
  }



 /// <summary>
  /// In order to create a multivalue dictionary it is necessary another class
  /// </summary>
  class ListIndex {
  public int Column { get; set; }
  public int Row { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't really help without a sample of your code.  We can't see why you're having trouble with `WriteRecords()` nor can we see why the array having an unknown number of elements has anything to do with your class (since a class property can have an undefined array at runtime).

Comment: For `double[]` you can have between 1 and 75 items. but, how many items do you have on the `List<>`?

Comment: I have updated with all the code. In List I usually have around 3000.

Comment: Try reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
I guess most of the code here is not of any use.

Comment: Simple in code  : List<double> data = new List<double>() { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };
            string csv = string.Join(",", data);

Comment: I'd go with @jdweng's solution. Don't bother with any other libraries.